# Dynamic code injection plugins for Xcode

Tags: xcode, code-injection

So far I've used [injection for Xcode](http://injectionforxcode.com/) plugin. In short:

> Using Injection it is possible to make a change to the implementation of an Objective-C® class and have it take effect as soon as the class is saved without having to restart the application.

It's a great plugin for Xcode, but it has some limitations (out of question scope) that spoil the overall good impression...

I still haven't tested [Dynamic Code Injection](http://dyci.github.io/), but it should do the same type of job:

> Dynamic Code Injection will boost your productivity by saving the time you waste while waiting for project to recompile and restart on simulator. In other words, no more standby between altering your code or resources and seeing the actual result.

So my question is can you recommend some other similar tools/plugins for dynamic code injection? Or at least have you heard of some simmilar stuff?